# Login form validation without reload page

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend

I have a login form that I would like to confirm without reloading the page. How can I do that? AJAX or Express (NodeJS)?

```
<form class="login-form" method="POST" @submit.prevent>
<p>Login to the chat.</p>
<br>
<p>Login:</p> <input type="text">
<p>Password:</p> <input type="password">
</form>
```

Comment: If you want your client-side code to communicate with your server-side code without reloading the page then, yes, AJAX is the technology you're looking for.  There are a variety of examples and tutorials available to get you started.

Comment: ok. i'll try ajax, thx.

Comment: hmm.. I will need to verify the data with the database)

Comment: Yeah, definitely backend then. This is a bit broad, so I recommend adding some server code and yes, use ajax to make a POST request to the server with the form data. The server will verify it against the database and send a response to the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U should first remove your "form" tag and add a button witch activates an function e.g "login"

I would recommend using axios:

In your function "login" u write:

```
    axios.post('/loginpath', {
    name: 'Fred',
     password:  'Flintstone'
     })
    .then(function (response) {
     if(response == "ok")
     { 
      window.location.replace("http://website.com/redirect);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
        });
```

On the serverside you catch the request something like

```
    app.post("/loginpath", (req,res) => {
    res.send("ok")
    })
```

You will need to i stall "bodyparser" to get the data from your body.
When you install bodyparser you can access the submitted data with req.body.name or req.body.password

Comment: ok, it works, but res.send("ok") don't works, haha. Idk why. Maybe because I have a vuejs modal window

Comment: before you send an response you set an session so the user is logged in. after setting the session you can send him an object back like res.send({loggedIn: true}). and then you check: if(response == true) you redirect him to your dashboard or whatever

Comment: ah okey, thats great